# HBase storefile format and column family

Tags: hadoop, hbase

On the one hand each column family  corresponds to a directory of hdfs where its storefiles are located

On the other hand each row in store file has format:

[rowkey][columnFamily][columnQualifier][timestamp]value

What's the point to store [columnFamily] in file? Is it redundant?

Comment: One of the reasons is to have a uniform byte representation of the KV both in memstore and in storefile.

Comment: Memstore and store file  constains data only from one column family.